# SQL Matching query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 tables, one with Candidates and one with Job Offers.

**Candidates:**

```
CandidateID
First Name
Last Name
Email
Address
City
State
```

**Job Offers:**

```
JobID
CompanyName
Address
City
State
```

What query do I have to run to get all the candidates that have the same state as the Job state?

And also what is the best option to connect data fields from a website to a database? What kind of database should I use, except MySQL?

Comment: A `select` would probably do the trick...

Comment: select * from candidates where ....... can you help me after where

Comment: You need to learn [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Comment: `select c.* from candidates as c inner join joboffers as j on c.state = j.state`

Comment: The same state as which job state?   Is this only to look at a specific job?

Comment: The select statement from Nepali Rookie is working. Is it possible to specify the state from the keyboard when I run the query?

Comment: Can you please include the current query you're stuck on?

Comment: `SELECT c.*, j.companyname
FROM  Candidates as C 
INNER JOIN Job as J on c.desiredjobstate = j.state `  It's working nice, but if its possible I would like to add the parameter myself before i run the query. Im using microsoft access

Comment: @Nadin you will probably want to create a stored procedure that passes a parameter (@state). That way, the program or the user can pass whatever the value needed to achieve desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain my comments above further, you could either create a stored procedure to pass your state parameter something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCandidatesByState 
@state varchar(2)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    SELECT c.*
          ,j.companyname
    FROM Candidates AS C
    INNER JOIN Job AS J ON c.desiredjobstate = j.[STATE]
    WHERE c.desiredjobstate = @state;
END
```

Or, simply declare a variable @state and pass a value something like this:

```
DECLARE @state VARCHAR(2);
SET @state = 'NY';
BEGIN
    SELECT c.*
          ,j.companyname
    FROM Candidates AS C
    INNER JOIN Job AS J ON c.desiredjobstate = j.[STATE]
    WHERE c.desiredjobstate = @state;
END
```